# AWS API Gateway "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" when trying to post a response to a websocket

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a creatred a basic websocket service using AWS lambda + api gateway using golang and AWS SDK v2.

I works correctly when using an ACM generated certificate but when i try using a self-signed certificate imported into ACM throw this error:

```
request send failed, Post "https:/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/dev/@connections/xxxxxxxxxxxx": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

The certificate is correctly generated and the import works.

I actually can access using https and view the certificate and the chain.

I can also connect to the websocket correctly, but the problem is when
the websocket lambda handler tries to post a response to the client.

Is there a way a to tell to AWS apigatewayadmin api running on a lambda not check for a valid CA ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the issue was this, when you reply to a websocket message from a lambda you need to call the `PostToConnection`  method to reply to a specific connection.

For doing this you need to build you `apigatewaymanagementapi` client defining an endponit to your current service url.

To do that on all the examples they use this method:

```
        config, _ := external.LoadDefaultAWSConfig(request.RequestContext.DomainName)
    config.EndpointResolver = aws.ResolveWithEndpointURL(
            fmt.Sprintf("https://%s/%s",
                    request.RequestContext.DomainName,
                    request.RequestContext.Stage))

    apigw := apigatewaymanagementapi.New(config)
```

The `request.RequestContext.DomainName` is defined with the request url and it works when you use the api gateway generate url in the format {api-id}.execute-api.{aws-zone}.com.

When you use a `custom domain name` with a different CA than AWS this code fails because lambda tries to post to that url.

My solution was replacing the request.RequestContext.DomainName to the generated endpoint {api-id}.execute-api.{aws-zone}.com

**Update:**

You can build the endpoint within your lambda using AWS_REGION env variable and RequestContext.APPID like this:

```
fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.execute-api.%s.com/%s",
            request.RequestContext.APPID,
            os.Getenv("AWS_REGION"),
            request.RequestContext.Stage)
```